# Definition of QFT in Vertex Operator Algebra by Kac

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space

QFT is composed of the following data with some axioms(I omitted them here).

(1) Hilbert space $H$.

(2) Vacuum belongs to $H$.

(3) There is unitary representation of Poincare group.

(4) A collection of fields $\Phi_a$ with $a$ as index, operator valued distributions on $R^{3,1}$ space time.(That is continuous linear functional $f\to\Phi_a(f)$ on the space of rapidly decreasing $C^{\infty}$ tensor valued test functions on $R^{3,1}$ with values in the space of linear operators densely defined on $H$.)

$\textbf{Q:}$ This is related to $(4)$. If I understand the statement correctly, I need $\Phi_a(f)$ to be an operator acting on a densely defined subset of $H$. What is $\Phi_a(f)$ in typical example? I could take $f=(\vec{x},t)$ and $\Phi$ to be standard "scalar field" which seems different from the requirement of linear functional on space of rapidly decreasing test functions.

Ref. Chpt 1, Sec 1.1. Vertex Algebras for Beginners Kac.

Comment: I found Kacs book on Vertex Algebras virtually unreadable. I guess it was a work in progress at the time.

Answer (score 0):

In QFT we talk about fields (like a scalar field $\phi$ in a free scalar theory) or composite operators $\mathcal{O}$ (like $: \phi^2 :$ or $: \phi \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi:$ etc.  in a scalar theory). In general we treat them on an equal footing, I don't know Kac's book but I'm assuming it does. We know that fields and operators depend on position: $\mathcal{O}(t,\vec{x})$ or $\mathcal{O}(x^\mu)$ depending on which notation you like. More generally for any function $f(x^\mu)$, you can define a "smeared" operator
$$
\hat{\mathcal{O}}(f) \, \equiv \int d^dx \, f(x^\mu) \mathcal{O}(x^\mu).
$$
If you take $f(x^\mu)$ to be a delta function, you recover the original function. For instance, if $f_a(x^\mu) = \delta(x^\mu - a^\mu)$ then
$$
\hat{\mathcal{O}}(f_a) = \mathcal{O}(a^\mu).
$$
But more generally, you can take any function $f$ that roughly looks like a Gaussian, i.e. it takes a maximum at some point $x^\mu = a^\mu$ and falls off quickly near infinity.

The reason this is useful or even necessary is that correlation functions $G(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of $n$ fields/operators are divergent when two insertions approach one another: $x_i \sim x_j$. By smearing with test functions $f$, you can keep track of such divergences without having to deal explicitly with infinities.

Comment: I do not think this address the need of smooth rapidly decreasing function. This definition is more general as in your case, one has to demonstrate that the linear map is indeed only given by that form.(One probably needs to mimick Riesz representation theorem but in field theoretical context the operator may not fall off at infinity in general.)